# the down arrow on a scrollbar disappears

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables, scrollbar

I have a datatable and every time I make the browser width pretty small (I don't know exactly, but it's less than like 700 or so.) the down arrow on the scrollbar goes off the screen, below where it should be. but if I make the width bigger, the scrollbar is there perfectly. I tried the following:

```
$("#table-tab").find('.dataTables_scrollHead').css('overflow-x', 'hidden'); 

$("#table-tab").find('.dataTables_scroll').css('overflow-x', 'auto'); 

$("#table-tab").find('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('overflow-x', 'auto');
```

but nothing will work to fix it. I don't understand why it's perfect when the screen is wider, but not when the screen is smaller. Any help?

Comment: I guess is because you have a fixed width for your #table-tab ...

Comment: @Danko, i have to have a fixed width for my datatable. why would that affect the scrollbar in some browser screen widths but not others?

Comment: It can happen if this scrollbar is practically not the scrollbar of the page, but the scrollbar of an internal element. Maybe this internal div is going out of the page? I am nearly sure this is the case. Another suggestion: avoid tables. You will always worry because of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What had happened: 
since I was making my tables smaller, the headers were getting crunched and getting taller. What I did is shorten the headers to make it the same size. Not an end-all fix, but it worked for me.